# Compiling python using PyInstaller throws many WARNINGS

Tags: python, pycharm, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an EXE file from my python script which I wrote in PyCharm. I am using the newest version of Python and using PyInstaller on a virtualenv.

The problem occurs whenever I try to actually use the command `pyinstaller --onedir map.spec` with map.spec being the spec file of my script, included here:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['map.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\BGBSC\\Desktop\\untitled'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('nactiMapu.txt', '.'), ('nactiPohyb.txt', '.'), ('nactiZnacky.txt', '.'), ('a.txt', '.'), ('b.txt', '.'), ('c.txt', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='map',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='map')
```

Whenever I try to run pyinstaller several warnings of this type show up:

```
5447 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
```

With every one of them referencing python38.dll, only difference being that they are 'dependant' on a different module. It also writes this line, which is probably also cause for concern:

```
5623 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
5631 INFO: Using Python library
```

My script uses these imports:

```
import sys
import os
import turtle
import time
```

***It is a turtle script that draws something. I also manipulate different txt files*** that I included as datas so they get exported with the final exe (at least how I understand it).

I am probably missing something very basic or maybe the newest Python is just not supported with pyinstaller, or is it just not able to find my python38.dll (I added the paths to the environmental).

Comment: I have not seen this problem however have you installed python from the windows store? Im thinking that might be an issue. I would suggest downloading python 3.8 from the official python website and trying pyinstaller using that python.

Comment: It’s only a warning - does the generated code run?

Comment: I have python downloaded from the official site, but I also downloaded one from the windows store today. I will uninstall all of them and reinstall just the official one and get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The generated code shows a console for like .1 seconds and then instantly closes itself. When I try to run it using the cmd, it outputs this error: Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\BGBSC\Desktop\untitled\dist\map\'. And: LoadLibrary: The specified module was not found.

Comment: @Har Yes! This fixed everything. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Store python is stated to be experimental and probably should be avoided for developers.
I would suggest downloading and using the Python from python.org for developers.